# Cannot deploy next js project contains Material-UI module

Tags: next.js, material-ui, netlify, vercel

I tried to deploy my NextJS app in Vercel, but I stuck with these errors, It seems like Vercel could not install the dependencies from Material-UI or something like that, anyone could figure it out?

[the log says like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNUqG.png)

I've tried to deploy normal nextJS app (without installing MUI) and it was normally fine and succeed, but it gone to be crashed when I added MUI, anyone please could help me